# How do I list commands associated with non-custom desktop keybindings?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, dconf, gsettings

I already know how to determine the command associated with a *custom* desktop keybinding (keyboard shortcut) in relatively recent Linux Mint versions running the Cinnamon desktop environment. My preference is to do this from the command line:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list
['custom0', 'custom1']
$ gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding binding ['<Super>m']
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding command '/usr/bin/xed'
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding name 'SomeBinding'
```

I also know how to determine which key sequences are bound to built-in (non-custom) keybindings, such as these for launching a calculator and muting the microphone:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys calculator
['XF86Calculator']
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys mic-mute
['XF86AudioMicMute']
```

What I want to know, however, is which command is associated with any given built-in keybinding. This can be learned empirically, of course, but that's not trivial in many cases. In my case that calculator binding maps to `/usr/bin/gnome-calculator`, but how/where is that mapping made?

More generally, how do I list the commands associated with **all** such built-in keybindings? I expected this to be in the `dconf` data store, but have been unable to find it. Scouring the file system hasn't yielded anything yet either.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3, but I suspect the answer to this question should be very similar for any distribution relying on `dconf`.